# debugging jaxb2 maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I have the following error while generate Java code from xsd using maven-jaxb2 plugin, it all working well using xjc from command line. Anyone knows how to debug maven-jaxb2 plugin?

```
[INFO] --- maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.3:generate (default) @ microsoft-windowsazure-api ---
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/D:/SRC/gcheng13/azure-sdk-for-java-pr/microsoft-azure-api/src/main/resources/schemas.microsoft.com.netservices.2010.10.servicebus.connect.xsd{155,87}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/SRC/gcheng13/azure-sdk-for-java-pr/microsoft-azure-api/src/main/resources/schemas.microsoft.com.netservices.2010.10.servicebus.connect.xsd; lineNumber: 155; columnNumber: 87; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tnsn:MessageCountDetails' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4124)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4107)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1667)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:405)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDElementTraverser.java:194)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseLocalElements(XSDHandler.java:3580)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:622)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:588)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:555)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:521)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:240)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.check(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:109)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:360)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:54)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:44)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:29)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:318)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:160)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix the issue at hand you should change the imports like this:

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="schemas.microsoft.com.2003.10.Serialization.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
<xs:import schemaLocation="schemas.microsoft.com.netservices.2011.06.servicebus.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2011/06/servicebus"/>
```

This is not an error, but there are way too many declarations in the schemas.microsoft.com.netservices.2011.06.servicebus.xsd.

I personally wouldn't declare/import anything I don't use to keep the schemas simple.

I moved the xjb file in to the same directory as the xsd files, so the schemalocations are valid now.

Comment: can u email me the final result? it is still not clear to me what makes it working ...

Comment: sure, but you mainly have to reference the schemas in the imports (the schemaLocation attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the namespace (tnsn) is declared in the xsd. And if it is, then it might be an inaccessible xsd import, which could up in an error like this.
Otherwise: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide
debug and verbose options are available...

Comment: If I use xjc command line, I can get it compiled correctly, it just doesn't work when it is run via maven-jaxb2 plugin. After turning on debug and verbose, it does out put more information, it confirmed that the .xsd file can be found.

Comment: Maybe not the best approach, but is this the xsd? https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-api/src/main/resources/schemas.microsoft.com.netservices.2010.10.servicebus.connect.xsd
I can't event find this type in it.

Comment: I am updating it, it is a work in progress, if I can have ur email, I can send u the latest.

Comment: I've sent you an email through your msdn blog with my contact info.